# Getting JSON content from HttpActionContext

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to get JSON content from HttpActionContext.

I thought that I would be able to do:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

var test = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

var test2 = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

but none of these work. My test variables are always empty, even though I am passing JSON content in my POST request. Could someone explain to me please how I can get what I am after?

Comment: Can you share what your scenario is? I see that you are trying to read the content after model binding is happening...ModelBinding reads the request stream to bind data to model and so the stream's position could be at the end...you would need to explicitly set the position back to the beginning to get the original content...

Comment: I would like to save the JSON content to our database for logging purposes. How would I set the position back to the beginning? It is probably exactly what I am after.